# NSString shows only the memory address when I try to compare with another NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a `NSString`called `insideString` that is globally defined inside in the **.h** file. In `viewdidload` i'm assigning some string to that `insideString` variable. After few statements im calling another method using a `NSTimer`.

Inside that method I want to compare this `insideString` variable with another string. But at that time. this `insideString` variable becomes empty. when I print that variable at this point, it shows only the memory address.

```
NSString *strnewinsideString = [strM3u81 substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
if ([strnewinsideString isEqualToString:insideString]) {            
    [self downloadM3u8:sender];
}
else
{
    insideString=strnewinsideString;
}
```

this what I want to do. But here `insideString` always shows its memory address. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: before compare check both string value .insideString empty means some where its going empty

Comment: Put `NSLog` to see the value, sometimes debugger sucks.

Comment: *I have a NSString called insideString that is globally defined inside in the .h file.*  That does not compute.  Show us how `insideString` is declared and initialized.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not your string is probably dealloc when the autorelease pool is flushed. You have to retain or, better, copy the string you are assigning to insideString.

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code is making your string empty: `insideString=strnewinsideString;` in your `else` block. So, I think if you want to persist your `insideString`, you should use some other temporary pointer for that line. Good Luck!

Comment: I check the code step by step,, before its going to the else part, at the begining of the comparison its going empty. but inside the viewdidload method I assign some value into that. that exist untill viewdidload finish

Comment: Maybe, somewhere else you are assigning different value to it? Please, double check your code.